# Swift - Low res firebase photo downloaded using URL

Tags: swift, firebase, uiimage, sdwebimage

I have searched for an answer to this but didn't find a working one.

My app can be logged in to via Google or Facebook.

In my "Personal Area", I display the profile picture related to that account.

```
@IBOutlet weak var PersonalImage: UIImageView!
```

This is the function I use:

```
func loadProfilePicture()
{
    let currentUser = Auth.auth().currentUser
    PersonalImage.sd_setImage(with: currentUser?.photoURL, completed: nil) // Done using SDWebImage
}
```

Function's previous iteration:

```
func loadProfilePicture()
    {
        let currentUser = Auth.auth().currentUser
        if let data = try? Data(contentsOf: (currentUser?.photoURL!)!)
        {
            PersonalImage.image = UIImage(data: data)
        }
    }
```

Unfortunately, the image I get from using Firebase's `photoURL` is low res and blurry and I'd like to make it better looking.

The Image:

[image]

1) How can I download the image in high res ?
2) Which iteration is more recommended? Notice that in the current one (Using SDWebImage) it takes a while for image to load
3) What is the best methodology for showing a "Loading Image" indication?

Answer (score 1):

When you upload the image to Firebase, you will be using either `UIImageJPEGRepresentation` or `UIImagePNGRepresentation`. If you use `UIImageJPEGRepresentation`, you'll be able to set how much the image is compressed like so:

```
UIImageJPEGRepresentation(yourImage, 1.0) // Highest quality
UIImageJPEGRepresentation(yourImage, 0.1) // Really low quality
```

Comment: But as you can see I am not calling it from Firebase , I am using the current user token